# IAS migrate from 2003 server to 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, radius, windows-ias-server, netsh

I have recently upgraded all our DC's from 2003 svr to 2008 r2 servers.
I had a radius server in the existing environment for 8021x authentication.

I successfully exported the configuration to a text file and successfully imported it into 2008 r2 server after installing NPS server (using the netsh commands to export and import the configuration).
The problem is that my radius configuration on the 2008 r2 server is blank. Non of the policies have copied across even though the import said it was successful.
Any other ideas before I start to manually copy over all the policies and reconfigure the radius server?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that there is a tool in server 2008 r2 that called Iasmigreader.exe that you copy to your existing IAS server then run it and it creates a text file.
You can then import this text file in 2008 r2 NPS server and it works.

Thanks